# Cleaning up geometry after Boolean cuts

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have used the boolean modifier to cut windows into this wall. However, it seems to have resulted in messy geometry. What would be the most efficient way to clean it up?

[image: Blender screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, and by the way you could have done it without booleans. Use the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>E</kbd> to continue, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to validate). To delete the bad edges, select them and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

[image]

You could try to simplify, actually it all depends on what you're planning to do later, but as Gorgious says you'll need to keep some edges between your holes and the external edges:

[image]

Comment: there is no way for the mesh to exist without the edges between the corners and windows? perhaps similar to a vector compound path?

Comment: No because a face with a hole can't exist in Blender, all the edges of a polygon must be somehow connected